# Send array data in api call php

Tags: php, api, curl

I hvae to call AT&T api for getting the userinfo using the following parameter

```
$a=array( 'Target'=>'UserPermissions',
         'Username'=>'isingh',
         'RightID'=>array("Param" => 1, "Param" => 6, "Param" => 17, "Param" 
 => 16, "Param" => 12,"Param" => 18));
```

How i will pass this in the curl

```
this is simple llok what i am doing
$a=array( 'Target'=>'GetUsers',
         'Origin'=>array('Param' => 1));
 $aa=http_build_query($a);
     $Url = "http://apiee.uc.att.com/apiee/api/api.asp?".$aa;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$res = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($res); echo "</pre>";
```

This code is working fine, there is no nested array in $a

Comment: What you have so far in curl code ?

Comment: You can't define the same key on multiple values in an array.

Comment: This `array("Param" => 1, "Param" => 6, "Param" => 17, "Param" => 16, "Param" => 12,"Param" => 18) === array("Param" => 18)` is **TRUE**

Answer (score 1):

You should read the PHP.net cURL reference.

An easy Google Search lead me here [curl_setopt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

On this page you'll find the `CURLOPT_POST` option that can be used with cURL.

You'll have to recursively go through each array element and set it as a cURL option with `curl_setopt`.

Comment: some actuall links would be helpfull :-)

Comment: this is simple llok what i am doing
$a=array( 'Target'=>'GetUsers',
    'Origin'=>array('Param' => 1));
 $aa=http_build_query($a);
$Url = "http://apiee.uc.att.com/apiee/api/api.asp?".$aa;
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$res = simplexml_load_string(curl_exec($ch));
    curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($res); echo "</pre>";
This code is working fine, there is no nested array in $a